# java best way assigning existing reference to new object

Tags: java

I am looking for a best approach for assigning existing reference to a new Object.
I am expecting something like deleting the old object created by parent class before it gets assigned to new object from subclass.

```
MyClass extends BaseClass{
    this.myClient = BaseClass.getClient(); //always i get a new object created here
    overrideClient();// i need to create a new object for same reference.


    overrideClient(){
        this.myClient = MyClass.getClient();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to "delete" the old object. That's what the Garbage Collector is for.

Of course, you could avoid the creation of the object that's going to be overridden if you make the assignment in some method, say, `setClient()`, and override that method in the sub class.

```
public class BaseClass {
...
    setClient ()
    {
        this.myClient = BaseClass.getClient();
    }
...
}

public class MyClass extends BaseClass {
...
    setClient ()
    {
        this.myClient = MyClass.getClient();
    }
...
}
```

This would save the allocation of an object that's not going to be used.

Comment: Thanks, Is it best approach to assign to null before just calling the method to create a object. this.myClient = null; then call this.myClient = MyClass.getClient(); or not required.

Comment: @skk You don't have to, since the reference to the myClient member would be initialized to null by default.